# Blocking 'friends' from seeing group posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I am in a group for Buying and Selling on Facebook. A few of my friends are too but I do not want them to see my posts. These friends are 'restricted' on my account so they do not see statuses, etc. They are in-laws who are apparently obligatory to have as friends but the drama they create over me buying/selling is very frustrating.

I made a separate account for buying and selling but Facebook shut it down, so that's not an option.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately not. If the group is public, posts will be pushed to your activity. In addition, since they are in the same group, privacy settings don't really apply, as they are allowed to read any message within the group.

https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465/

[image: What are the privacy options for groups?]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going to settings, then go to privacy. Next, go down to "Your Activity", then go to "who can see your future posts", and click edit. Click the "Friends" button then "Friends Except" option. You can select each friend from the drop-down list or type their name then the save button. All your posts will be shared except to the ones you selected. You can change it back just as easily. I hope this helps.

Comment: Won't they still see the posts because they are both members of the same group.